# Character encoding issue in REST.POST

Tags: java, spring, rest, post, special-characters

I have to receive a message from AJAX request which might be a error or stack trace.So I am using REST API (POST) to receive and write into a log file.I am receiving this message as a String in Request body of POST request.When  I write the content into log file i am getting space and newline replaced with \t,\n etc.
Even though the content type has been setted with UTF 8 encoding on both requestside(When send msg thro AJAX) and API .

```
Example :
Input msg :
 Error occured on this
 line null .
Received msg:
 Error\toccured\ton\tthis\t\n
 line\tnull.
```

Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your log file does not seem to be UTf-8 encoded.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Even I printed the received message in console It returns the same.

Comment: Console is generally not UTF-8 encoded also. Check your file & console settings for encoding to be sure.

Comment: \t and \n escapes are not related to UTF-8 encoding, so that's not the issue. It's a way to escape tabs and newlines in source code so that you can include them in string literals without confusion or problems. Your message somehow gets encoded that way: you need to show the code that does the writing to the log file, something is happening there.